# HB100 range extension with dish antenna

Tags: rf, antenna, motion, radar

I have interfaced an [HB100](http://openimpulse.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/wpsc/downloadables/HB100_Microwave_Sensor_Module_Datasheet.pdf) sensor with an ATMega microcontroller. It easily detects my hand movement upto 5-6" away only.

I want to extend the range of the sensor so that it detects movement upto at least 10 m. I see people use a dish antenna.

For that it requires LNB. I have no knowledge of RF, can someone please suggest how do I select LNB for the HB100? Or any other way to extend the sensing range which can save me from using LNB stuff?

[image]

Comment: A 5-6 inch detection range would indicate something is wrong with your setup.  Are you *moving* the target?  Although sometimes misrepresented as a "distance sensor" (shockingly in places that should know better, like Mouser) **this is a *doppler* sensor only able to detect motion.**  Also make sure it's not being distracted, eg any sort of fan can easily trigger these.  That said you're probably not going to get 10 meters from something like this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i am not detecting distance, I am detecting speed but the problem is it detects movement from a few inches only. It does not responds to any movement happened beyond this distance.

Comment: Then there's something wrong with your particular unit or setup.  You should get at least a few meters.

Comment: Any idea what can be wrong with my setup?

Comment: Maybe coupled noise, maybe a bad module

Comment: Regarding noise can you please have a look at my circuit. attached in the question.

Comment: Your circuit doesn't include any of the coupled components - power supply, Arduino, etc.  But rather than posting those, do a test which eliminates them - batteries, simpler output, etc.  Also get another example of such a module to try.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at a teardown of the HB100 module, it appears that the antenna is a pair of two-element patch arrays (one for TX, one for RX) on the back of the board. There's no coaxial out. It'll be very difficult to bodge it into a standard feed horn for a dish.

You might be able to install the module itself at the focus of an old VSAT dish, with the antenna face of the module pointed at the reflector. This isn't super ideal: the patches aren't designed to be a dish feed, so your aperture efficency will likely be pretty awful as you won't illuminate the whole dish and/or you'll have signficant spillover. But, it might work in a pinch.

Either way, keep in mind that you are increasing the EIRP of the module by doing this, and that you may run into regulatory issues if it's too high. I'd suggest learning more about RF and radar before attempting this.

Comment: I have placed the sensor right in the center of the dish without any LNB etc. it still responds to really close motion only.